# If domain A calls a web service on domain B, can the web service running on domain B read/write cookies? If so, on which domain, A or B?

Tags: cookies

If domain A calls a web service on domain B, can the web service running on domain B read/write cookies? If so, on which domain, A or B? Sorry for the long question but it seems like a straight forward enough question.

Comment: The web service gets only cookies that have been sent to it by a client. So, your question must be rephrased to address an http client behaviour.

Comment: Assuming I'm not calling the web service from the client (browser)...if the system calling the service passes the headers/request/whatever then B can read/write cookies on A?

Comment: Or does A have to pass a literal cookie collection to B and would B have to return that collection and have A take specific action on the returned data?

Comment: "if the system calling the service passes the headers/request/whatever then B can read/write cookies on A" --- if a client has sent them - yes, if it has not - no.

Comment: excellent, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't really understand what cookies are or how they work.

An analogy may help.

If Alice and Bob are having a conversation, and Bob tells Alice "x = 1", Alice will store this and associate it with Bob.  If Alice then has a conversation with Bruce, and Bruce tells Alice "x = 2", Alice will also store that, but associated with Bruce.

The next time Alice talks to either of them, she will tell them the value that they last told her.

Bob and Bruce can also talk to each other in this fashion, and the values they store can be completely different, and will be private between them.

Edit: Worth noting, at no point will Alice tell Bob the value she has received from Bruce, nor will she tell Bruce the value she received from Bob.  Neither Bob nor Bruce tells Alice "hey, this is from Bob" -- Alice already knows who it's from, it's from the person she's talking to.  Neither Bruce nor bob has any say in that.

Comment: That's not a helpful analogy. Cookies are set by the browser. I'm not sure if the people in your statement are browsers or domains or a mixture. You seem to use them interchangeably. In my question, Bob doesn't talk to Alice (the browser) but speaks directly to Bruce, since the browser stores the conversation I was curious which, if any, side of the conversation it understood. I thought I knew the answer, and I did, but thinking is not the same as knowing so I asked.

Comment: You stated "domain A calls a webservice on domain B" is "domain A" not acting as a client instead of a server?  Also, cookies are not set by the browser -- they are set by the server.